# How to get details such as score, correct answer from package running with tincan?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tin-can-api

I have a tincan package by which I play the activities, from the package I need to get the score is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will not get the score from the package. The content is most likely communicating with an LRS via xAPI and recording data via xAPI statements. You would then request the statements from the LRS via xAPI, parse the statements, and based on how the content records such data you would determine the statement containing the data you need and retrieve it from there. All of this is dependent on how that package is authored, the types of statements that are sent, and having access to the LRS where the data has been recorded. There are a number of libraries available to make communicating with an LRS via xAPI simpler. See a list here: https://experienceapi.com/libraries

In general long term, cmi5 is a better package implementation specification that makes it more clear how to record typical LMS based e-learning content. In that specification it is clear how to locate a score provided by the content.